# Derivation of Posterior Density in Tweedie's Formula

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

I'm stuck on understanding a chain of reasoning in the paper Tweedie's Formula and Selection Bias by Efron ([link here](https://efron.ckirby.su.domains/papers/2011TweediesFormula.pdf)).
The following equations come from the beginning of section 2, equations 2.1-2.4.
We have the following setup
$$
\eta \sim g(\cdot), \quad \text{and} \quad z|\eta \sim f_{\eta}(z) = e^{\eta z - \psi(\eta)}f_0(z)
$$
Where $g$ is some unknown distribution, $z|\eta$ comes from an exponential family, $\psi(\eta)$ is the cumulant generating function so that the density integrates to 1, and $f_0(z)$ is the density of $z | \eta=0.$ Baye's rule gives the posterior density of $\eta | z$ as
$$
g(\eta | z) = f_{\eta}(z)g(\eta) / f(z)
$$
where $f(z)$ is the marginal density of $z,$
$$
f(z) = \int_{\mathcal{Z}}f_\eta(z)g(\eta)d\eta
$$
Here $\mathcal{Z}$ is the domain of the exponential family.

Now here's the part I don't understand how to recreate: given the equations above, the author claims

$$
g(\eta | z) = e^{z\eta - \lambda(z)}[g(\eta)e^{-\psi(\eta)}]
$$
Where $\lambda(z) = \log\left(\frac{f(z)}{f_0(z)}\right).$

If anyone can explain how the density of $\eta | z$ is being derived here I would greatly appreciate the help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Re-organize the right hand side,

$\begin{align}
& e^{z\eta - \Psi(\eta)} e^{-\lambda(z)} g(\eta) \\
=& \mathbf{e^{z\eta - \Psi(\eta)} f_0(z)}/f(z) g(\eta)\\
=& \frac{\mathbf{f_{\eta}(z)}g(\eta)}{f(z)} ,
\end{align}$

which is equivalent to $g(\eta|z)$.

The reason for choosing exponential family distribution is that it enables a conjugate prior, e.g., $g(\eta)$, and a closed-form posterior, $g(\eta|z)$.